# Killing a process that spawned a process

Tags: node.js, process, electron

I'm having trouble stopping a node.js process that spawns a child process. If I run the .js process from Terminal, I can stop it using `Ctrl+C`. But if I spawn it from a NodeJS app, I cannot kill it using `kill("SIGINT")` -- it just keeps going and continues to report `stdout`.

Here's the setup. I have a script, lets call it `docker.js` and it does this:

```
// docker.js
child_process.spawn("docker-compose", ["up", "-d", ...args], { stdio: 'inherit' });
```

The [`docker-compose up` command](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) does a lot of things and runs for awhile, sometimes for several minutes.

**If I run `./docker.js` from Terminal, I can consistently break out at any point by pressing `Ctrl+C`.**

If I spawn `docker.js` from inside *a different* NodeJS app (in my case an Electron app), using `spawn()` or `fork()`:

```
// DockerApp.js

const dir = `path/to/dockerjs/file/`;

// Tried this with and without `detached: true`
const child = spawn("node", [`./docker.js`, ...args], { cwd: dir, env, detached: true });

// Also tried this, which uses Electron's packaged node process
const child = fork(`./docker.js`, args, { cwd: dir, env, silent: true });
```

And I listen for `stdout` and `stderr` and `close`:

```
child.stdout.on("data", data => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

child.stderr.on("data", data => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

child.on("close", code => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

Everything works fine (I see expected output and eventually "close" after completion), but if I try to stop the process before completion like this:

```
child.kill("SIGINT"); // Equivalent to Ctrl+C in terminal
```

The child process just keeps running, and I keep getting `docker-compose` output through `stdout`.

I've tried for awhile but I cannot figure out how to stop `docker.js` when spawned as a child process from NodeJS/Electron app. I thought `Ctrl+C` from Terminal and `child.kill("SIGINT")` would have the same behavior, but it doesn't.

Can anyone explain what is going on here? And how can I reliably kill this `docker.js` child process from my NodeJS app?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in child process:

```
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  console.log('Received SIGINT');
  process.exit(0);
});
```

Comment: Why would that be necessary when it exits when run from Terminal? Does a NodeJS process behave differently in a TTY?

Comment: I tried this. It does allow the `docker.js` process to exit (but my question remains why this is needed when from CLI it is not needed), but the child `docker-compose` process keeps running.

Comment: I've faced this issue outside docker. When used subprocesses in Node.js. I think the major difference here is the handling process - if subprocess - the handling one is your nodejs script, if you launch from CLI - it's some OS process.